# How to decrease the helm chart cert-manager log level?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I am using the https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/cert-manager.
It happens that I have a very frequent INFO logging. I was not yet able to find the source of that frequent logging. The problem is that the Google Cloud Platform Stackdriver feature is increasing in costs because of that high amount of logs.

Therefore I'd love to know how I can turn down INFO logging via the helm chart for the cert-manager.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: since kubernetes and helm appear as tags here I think it has to be ok. Also the DevOps term is implying development

Comment: Tags mean nothing in the context of on-topic/off-topic. What matters are the rules detailed in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: any suggestion where to ask these questions then

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the Helm chart for `cert-manager` from community charts has been deprecated. The suggested [official alternative](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/tree/dddc6abd2e0075648df2eddcff765b4986e9497d/deploy/charts/cert-manager) does support config option to specify loglevel since release v0.7.2. see this pull request [jetstack/cert-manager/1527](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/pull/1527).

So please use the official chart like:

```
$ helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
$ ## Install the cert-manager helm chart
$ helm install --name my-release --namespace cert-manager \
  jetstack/cert-manager --set global.logLevel=1
```